# Facebook Messages Never Delivered

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'll try to give all the details as best as possible:

- As a side note, I have had an account since '08, but was inactive for several years. I last messaged someone on the old system 4/5 years ago. I log in to find the new messenger system put in place. AFAIK on the desktop website the new messenger didn't affect how you send messages, other than the notification doesn't seem to be showing sometimes.
- I sent a message to someone **I'm friends with** using the *website* through a desktop browser.
- The friend does not have the messenger app on the phone (or least it says they don't when I installed the app on my phone). I had installed it after sending the original message, but wouldn't think this has anything to do with it.
- I've seen the friend be "active" according to FB and have a something like "1h ago" when I check if they responded on the messenger app I installed on my phone.
- It's been over a week and the message was still showing the "Sent" icon (Non-filled in check mark), but never shows the "Delivered" icon (Filled in check mark)
- I've sent another message which also didn't get delivered (I've stopped at this point, because I figure if the friend ever receives them they will get spammed with a bunch if I send any more).

Other Notes:

- I have sent messages both on the desktop website and on messenger to both old friends (like the one above) and new friends I've added since with no issue. They are noted on messenger as sent, delivered, and seen with no issue and show a check mark on the desktop website with "seen".
- I'm not blocked by the friend otherwise it should have given me a message.
- I don't feel the friend would be using a "message read" masking app considering they don't even have messenger installed.

Is there something I'm missing or does this sound like a problem on FB's end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned. Everything is fine, in your case I would think the problem as follows.

1. Your friend must be using some "read receipt blocker". Or
2. On client side read receipt js might is blocked. Or
3. May be some sever error (very rare.)

Comment: I could see blocking it from being marked as "seen", but not as being "delivered" by FB. I'm not even sure anyone could make a blocker for that since FB servers control it. My guess is FB has a server error here, but wanted to know if there was something else I was missing. Nothing I could do about it afaik, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Message sent means it has sent from your side. And deliver means it has reach to recipient side. If your message is not delivering that means problem is on recipient side. It could be server problem, internet problem, their settings problem, anything.

You can also test this by sending message to some more friends. If you face the same problem with each and every people every time, I would suggest you to contact Facebook help team: [Report an Issue with Confirming Your Facebook Account](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/174964429275926?rdrhc).

<sup>[Answer source](https://www.quora.com/I-messaged-someone-on-Facebook-and-its-been-sent-not-delivered-The-problem-is-the-person-has-gone-online-What-is-going-on/answer/Satyendra-Shukla-6?srid=7Iht)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

that friend of yours have received the message but haven't opened it yet. You may ask him/her if he/she is using the free mode in his/her browser in the phone. I've tried it and it shows active now but the icon was only sent not delivered.